# JavaScript: Set property of object based on index in array

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file which exports an array of objects in this format:

```
export const refData = [
 {
    type: "A",
 },
 {
    type: "D",
 },
 {
    type: "C",
 },
...
 {
    type: "A",
 },
];
```

I also have some image files in my projects that are named in numerical, sequential order, such that their filenames corresponds to an element in the array. The intention is that `refData` contains properties for files in my project. For example, 0.jpg corresponds to the element at index 0 in the `refData` array, and 3.jpg corresponds to the element at index 3.

The problem is that there's no easy way for me to tell which file corresponds to an element in the array. So if I have 28.jpg and I want to change its type contained in `refData` to something else, I have to manually count the elements to find out where to make the change.

The easiest solution to this would be if I could somehow see every element's index directly in my code editor. I use VSCode, so some way to notate element index using an extension or something else would be most helpful, though I'm also open to changing editors if this is not possible in VSCode. I looked into inlay hints for VSCode but it doesn't seem to contain this functionality, and manually counting is unsustainable as the array grows larger.

Edit: VS Code may not have this functionality, but Levi's answer below (using Object.defineProperty()) also works for my purposes.

Comment: @DaveNewton why did you remove the vscode tag?

Comment: This isn’t an editor problem, it’s a code/organization problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton he/she is asking if the editor can display the index at the cursor.  considering vscode has tons of contextual information to the user, i don't think they are asking about a code problem.

Comment: @Mulan Because IMO this isn’t a problem that should be solved by an editor. Feel free to add the tag back.

Comment: @DaveNewton Admittedly my question could've been clearer, but the title (and my primary question) is whether VSCode can show the feature I described, with the extra details only there in case someone sees a different solution besides the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @DaveNewton i agree the exports could be organized differently to make it easier to link relevant data, but that doesn't seem to be the focus of this question.

Comment: Seems like you have a very simple question ("can VS Code show me the index of an array entry"), but buried it in a ton of unrelated disclaimers. Maybe straighten that up?

Comment: @Mulan Not the exports, rather having a giant static array where you (as a human) want to know where you are in the **source**. For example, you could use a map and via code convert it to an array, or have standalone objects and the array would just be references. I’m all for offloading work to the IDE, but I remain unconvinced this is a good use case.

Comment: @DaveNewton i agree it's not optimal but make no assumptions about the skill level of the asker. if exporting a few arrays across multiple files is all they are doing, they might not know the first thing about data mapping or other complex transformations. asking if vscode can display array index is no different than asking if it can display cursor position or line number, imo.